# How to update specific model fields using Django UpdateView

Tags: django

How can you update certain model fields when a form is posted using Django's UpdateView?
When the user checks `complete = True` on the form, and submits it, I want their name and date to be saved to this record (fields not visible on the form). The code below isn't throwing any errors, but it also isn't updating the fields requested.

Is it potentially because the view is already updating this record with the form, so they conflict?

view:

```
class maintenanceEdit(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView,):
    model = Maintenance
    form_class = EditMaintenance
    template_name = 'maintenance_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('equipmentdashboard')

    def form_valid(self, form,):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        user = instance.user.first_name +" "+instance.user.last_name
        completed = form.instance.completed
        dateCompleted = form.instance.dateCompleted
        if (dateCompleted is None):
            if completed == True:
                updateMaintenance = Maintenance.objects.get(id = instance.id)
                updateMaintenance.dateCompleted = timezone.now()
                updateMaintenance.completedBy = user
                updateMaintenance.save(update_fields=['dateCompleted','completedBy',])
        return super(maintenanceEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```

model:

```
class Maintenance(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    customerTag = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    maintenanceItem = models.CharField(max_length=35,blank=True,)
    maintenanceDescrip = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True,)
    maintenanceNotes = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True,)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    dateDue = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    dateCompleted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    createdBy = models.CharField(max_length=35,blank=True,)
    completedBy = models.CharField(max_length=35,blank=True,)
```

form:

```
class EditMaintenance(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditMaintenance, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['maintenanceItem'].required = True
        self.fields['dateDue'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Maintenance
        fields = ['maintenanceItem','dateDue','maintenanceDescrip',
                'maintenanceNotes','completed',]

        labels = {
            'maintenanceItem': ('Maintenance Item'),
            'dateDue': ('Maintenance Due'),
            'maintenanceDescrip': ('Maintenance Description'),
            'maintenanceNotes': ('Maintenance Notes'),
            'completed': ('Complete Maintenance'),
        }
```

I also tried, in my view:

```
    def form_valid(self, form,):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        user = instance.user.first_name +" "+instance.user.last_name
        completed = form.instance.completed
        dateCompleted = form.instance.dateCompleted
        if (dateCompleted is None):
            if completed == True:
            Maintenance.objects.filter(id = instance.id).update(dateCompleted = timezone.now(),completedBy = user)
    return super(maintenanceEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: what happens with this code?

Comment: same thing, no error messages, but the fields simply do not update. I'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Is it potentially because the view is already updating this record with the form, so they conflict?

Comment: Is there a traceback you can show

Comment: This is all I see: 
`[21/Aug/2019 04:13:10] "GET /maintenance/21/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7218
[21/Aug/2019 04:13:10] "GET /static/images/horizontalText.png HTTP/1.1" 200 13070
[21/Aug/2019 04:13:14] "POST /maintenance/21/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0`

Comment: Shows the form load, then the post with a 302 which I believe is just my intended redirection

Comment: add `instance.save()` before `return ...`

Comment: Still not working... Thanks for your help here @henryM - I have moved on to accomplishing this by hiding the fields, then using javascript to autofill the fields when the form is submitted. This feels hacky, but I don't know how else to solve